# How do I uncheck the checkbox

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, html, slds, inputcheckboxes

I need to uncheck the checkbox on click of a button, but I'm using the checkbox inside the aura:iteration and on using aura:id I'm getting the value as undefined.
My Actual Scenario is like there are multiple buttons, if I click on a button, checks the checkbox and then click on the cancel button and click on another button, the checkboxes which I checked earlier retains.

```
<aura:iteration items = "{!v.UserWrapper}" var = "col" indexVar = "index">
                <aura:if isTrue = "{!v.Segment == col.segment}">
                    <tr class="{! (index%2)==0?'':'altRow'}">
                        <th scope="row" width = "10%">
                            <div class="slds-truncate">
                                    <lightning:input type="checkbox" aura:id="checkboxField" onchange = "{!c.OnRemove}"/>
                            </div>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </aura:if>
            </aura:iteration>

CloseNav: function(component, event, helper) { // function called on Cancel button
        var checkBxVal = component.find('checkboxField').set("v.checked", false); // checkBxVal => undefined
        component.set("v.display", false);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if you have an Array or not.

```
var checkboxes = component.find("checkboxField");
if(checkboxes && !checkboxes.length) { // is an object, not an Array
    checkboxes = [checkboxes]; // Make this an array
}
if(checkboxes) {
    // Uncheck all boxes //
    checkboxes.forEach(function(cmp)) {
        cmp.set("v.checked", false);
    });
}
```

Find can return one of three possible values.

- `undefined` means there are no matches.
- `SecureComponent` means there was exactly one match.
- `Array` means there were two or more matches.

So, the code above converts the second condition into an Array, so we're left with either `undefined` or an `Array`, and we can then iterate over the `Array` and set the attributes.

Comment: @ sfdcfox thanks for Proactive response, var checkboxes = component.find("v.checkboxField") is always returning undefined irrespective of the aura:id and therefore its never satisfying any of the condition, my concern is there any way to get the values using aura:id inside aura:iteration?

Comment: @AbhishekGangwar Sorry, it should have been just `checkboxField`. The `v.` was a typo.